# PHP REST API with ETAG support?

Tags: php, api, rest, etag

Is there a possibility to create a REST API in PHP that supports ETags?

And if yes, how could you use parse the response in PHP to consider the ETags?

Comment: Is this the client or the server?

Comment: I'm actually asking for both. How to do it server-side, and what the client has to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the corresponding request headers in `$_SERVER` `If-Match`. Is the key `HTTP_IF_MATCH`, `If-None-Match` corresponds to `HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH`.

In order to send proper ETags to the client use the `ETag` header like `header( 'ETag: ' . generateEtag() );`. You just need to ensure that your ETag represents the response of the service properly.